# <ShinobiGrids/ShinobiGrids.h> file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, shinobi

I just updated my shinobigrids and I am looking at some sample codes the new has got and I tried to #import  but I got a file not found error. but I can see this files in the framework...why am I getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to check your framework search paths in the Xcode project file settings - they'll not be pointing at your framework I imagine